# C++ QLineEdit не выводится текст

Tags: c++, qt

Имею такой код

```
demo.h

private:
   QLineEdit *serialNumberText;


main.cpp

//СОЗДАЕТСЯ КНОПКА
QHBoxLayout *serial = new QHBoxLayout();
serial->addWidget(new QLabel("S/N:"));
serial->addWidget(serialNumberText);
serial->addWidget(serialNumberBtn);

//САМА ФУНКЦИЯ
void Main::serialNumberFunc(){
   std::cout << serialNumberText->text().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

После нажатия на кнопку, программа просто критически закрывается. Отладчик показывает Segmentation fault, на строку `std::cout << serialNumberText->text().toStdString() << std::endl;`

Comment: У вас serialNumberText инициализируется вообще?

Comment: @free_ze ну он выводится на экране или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Где у Вас выделение памяти(инициализация) `serialNumberText`?

Comment: Если отладчик уже указал Вам строку, попробуйте эту строку разделить на несколько действий, или как-то иначе модифицировать её. Этими действиями Вы сможете ещё более локализовать проблему, а как следствие - быстрее найти решение.

Comment: Вероятнее всего, вы используете форму созданную в дизайнере. А указатель `QLineEdit *serialNumberText` не инициализируете корректным значением.

Comment: @aleks.andr нет, я не использую форму созданную в дизайнере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему тем, что создал формы в дизайнере и получил нужные мне значения через

```
QString string = ui.lineEdit->text();
serialNumberPDF = string.toInt();
```

`lineEdit` в этом случае, это бывший `serialNumberText`

Comment: а теперь к выводу метода text добавьте .toLatin1().data(); и ненадо будет помещать его в QString, Вот тут рассматривали ваш вопрос https://forum.qt.io/topic/39486/solved-convert-content-of-qlineedite-to-char/4